# how to call the snooze feature on the button click of alertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have set an alarm through uilocalnotifications.so when my app is in background my local notification is displayed with 2 buttons close and view.when my app is in foreground it displays and alertview with 2 buttons ,stop and snooze.when the stop button is clicked i want that my alarm should stop and when snooze button is clicked i want that the notification should appear after 5 mins.How is this possible.Please help me in solving this prob.Thanks.

```
this is my code :


//this is my controller class where i am setting my notification

- (void)clearNotification {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}

- (void)scheduleNotification {

    [reminderText resignFirstResponder];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

        NSInteger index = [scheduleControl selectedSegmentIndex];
        switch (index) {
            case 1:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 2:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 3:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 4:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
                break;
            default:
                notif.repeatInterval = 0;
                break;
        }

        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:reminderText.text
                                                forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Public Methods ===
#pragma mark -

- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text {

    if (reminderText != nil) {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" 
                                                            message:text delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"stop",@"Snooze",nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];



    }




}
//this is my appdelegate where i am receiving my notification
- (void)clearNotification {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}

- (void)scheduleNotification {

    [reminderText resignFirstResponder];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

        NSInteger index = [scheduleControl selectedSegmentIndex];
        switch (index) {
            case 1:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 2:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 3:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                break;
            case 4:
                notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
                break;
            default:
                notif.repeatInterval = 0;
                break;
        }

        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:reminderText.text
                                                forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Public Methods ===
#pragma mark -

- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text {

    if (reminderText != nil) {
        /*newtest *new = [[newtest alloc]initWithNibName:@"newtest" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:new animated:YES];
        [new release];*/
    //  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert
//  didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex 
//      {
//          if (buttonIndex == 0)
//          {
//              NSLog(@"Cancel Tapped.");
//          }
//          else if (buttonIndex == 1) 
//          {    
//              NSLog(@"OK Tapped. Hello World!");
//          }
//      }

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" 
                                                            message:text delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"stop",@"Snooze",nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];


    }
```

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

```
if(buttonIndex == 0)  
{  
    NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");  
}  
else if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 2"])  
{  
    NSLog(@"Button 2 was selected.");  
}
```

}

```
//this is my appdelegate where i am receiving notification
NSString *kRemindMeNotificationDataKey = @"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey";

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === Application Delegate Methods ===
#pragma mark -

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls) {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:
                                UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

        if (notification) {
            NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo 
                                      objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
            [viewController showReminder:reminderText];
            /*newtest *new = [[newtest alloc]initWithNibName:@"newtest" bundle:nil];
            [window addSubview:new.view];*/
        }
    }

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    // UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    // if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        // Application was in the background when notification
        // was delivered.
    // }


    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo
                              objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
    [viewController showReminder:reminderText];
     NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notification);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click your snooze button you set another local notification. When you click in snooze button you call another function. In this you take current time and in fire date you set it with adding 5 minutes.

When your notification is coming then u take one alert in received notification delegate method and the button click of alert u call this function

Click on your snooze alert click u call this function.

```
-(void)addNewNotification{
        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];               
        localNotification.alertBody =@"HI"
        localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5*60];
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        [localNotification release];
        NSLog(@"%@",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
}
```

Comment: Ron,i am getting totally confused.Please can u provide some demo code on how to call another function which add 5 min to firedate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the alertview delegate method,clickedAtIndex.
Then check  if the index is what you want say 1 for snooze,then make it repeat after the 5 minutes.

Thanks

Comment: Sabby i tried to add the alertview code .But my breakpoint is not entering in the alertview delegate method when the alertview button is clicked

Comment: Can you show your Alert view delegate code? That's where the problem lies.

Comment: @Rocky, You have set `nil` as `delegate` while you create the alert view. You should set `delegate:self`.

Comment: @Empty stack is right ,if your delegate is nil,then how will it call the delegate you need to send it to current class and assign to selg...

Comment: i was also doing that mistake as i also have copied the same code and haven't modified it before using... :D well you got it right... :)